# 2 computers give different outputs

Tags: c++, double

Here is a part of my code (I epitomized it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double pi = M_PI;
    long long x = 12026548095792;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << pi * x;
}
```

My computer's output was:

```
37782515145784.46100000
```

(Windows 7 x64, processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20ghz).

But when I ran my code on SPOJ, the output was

```
37782515145784.46093750
```

(Cluster: Cube (Intel G860)).

Please help me explain this problem.

update: I used codeblocks 16.01, gcc version 5.3.0.

Comment: Also post the compile flags

Comment: Probably something like http://christian-seiler.de/projekte/fpmath/ or https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath might explain what happens. How to fix the issue depends on particular compiler you use and the set of target platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: It just means that the two implementations (compiler, host system) you're using employ different floating point representations.   A typical `double` supports precision to (about) 15-17 significant decimal figures.   The differences you are seeing are about the 16th significant figures.   Incidentally, `M_PI` is not standard either, although a few implementations support it.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Anyway can you show me if there is a way to change the precision of my compiler?

Comment: You'll need to read documentation for your compilers.   And that's assuming your chosen compilers CAN be configured to support floating point in different ways - most cannot.

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision of a double is about 15 digits, so the two numbers **are the same** (they differ in their own "rubbish part")

This is most likely due on how the FP unit internally work (may be 80 bits) and how double are treated when passed to the FP unit (may be by zero filling the precision excess or by simply carry rubbish to be faster)

Probably also the way `M_PI` is defined matters.
Have you tried something like `acos(-1)` ?

In general don't expect FP calculation to be exact and to be the same everywhere.